# C# When I execute a query dataTable is not loaded and the I obtain an expiration exeption

Tags: c#, database, datatable, sqlconnection

how are you ?

i have a problem loading data from DB (connexion string is good, since I can insert data into DB) into my data Table.

my query also works fine, when execute in Sql management studio I received 15 records... so after some lonely search and tries, I come to you.

Here is the code of my function supposed to get Value from DB.

The code stops at 'dt.Load(sqlCommand.ExecuteReader());' , where it seems to search, but i obtain after some seconds , a timeout exeption. And I as I

```
 public List<string> GetConfigurationValues(string configurationKey, int? idBusinessUnit, int? idDomain)
        {
            string conn = ConnectionStringHelper.GetIdentityConnectionString();


            List<string> conf = new List<string>();
            using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(conn))
            {
                dbConnection.Open();
                SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(@"
                        SELECT Value 
                        FROM ConfigurationValue cv
                        INNER JOIN ConfigurationFilter cf ON cv.idConfigurationValue = cf.idConfigurationValue
                        INNER JOIN ConfigurationKey ck ON ck.idConfigurationKey = cf.idConfigurationKey
                        WHERE ck.KeyName = @ConfigurationKey
                        AND((cf.idDomain = @idDomain) OR(cf.idDomain IS NULL))
                        AND((cf.idBusinessUnit = @idBusinessUnit) OR(cf.idBusinessUnit IS NULL))", dbConnection);
                sqlCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ConfigurationKey", "PORTAL_THEME"));

                if (idBusinessUnit == null)
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@idBusinessUnit", null)); //DBNull.Value
                else
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@idBusinessUnit", null));

                if (idDomain == null)
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@idDomain", null));// DBNull.Value
                else
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@idDomain", 281));


                DataTable dt = new DataTable();        
                dt.Load(sqlCommand.ExecuteReader());
                //dbConnection.Close();

                if (dt != null)
                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                            conf.Add(Convert.ToString(dr["Value"]));
            }
            return conf;
        }
```

Comment: do you access to DB‌ via web or windows?; If you are using web apps, and your query is time consuming, it is possible that your connection pool setting of IIS‌ needs to be modified

Comment: Please post the exception too

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(@"
                        SELECT Value 
                        FROM ConfigurationValue cv
                        INNER JOIN ConfigurationFilter cf ON cv.idConfigurationValue = cf.idConfigurationValue
                        INNER JOIN ConfigurationKey ck ON ck.idConfigurationKey = cf.idConfigurationKey
                        WHERE ck.KeyName = @ConfigurationKey
                        AND((cf.idDomain = @idDomain) OR(cf.idDomain IS NULL))
                        AND((cf.idBusinessUnit = @idBusinessUnit) OR(cf.idBusinessUnit IS NULL))", dbConnection);

sqlCommand .CommandTimeout = 500;
```

Comment: hi SilentTremor, thank you but i solved it thisw morning. i was a probleme in the way I axecuted the load of the dataTable. instead of a dataTable, I used a DataReader. i precise, that if we use the datareader, we get the right error message (it s a bonus.) So here is the part of the cod I changed (for thoose who want to know) :

Answer (score 0):

thank you, for your kind attention.I solved it this morning. it was a probleme in the way I excecuted the load of the dataTable. Instead of a dataTable I am using now a DataReader. I precise, that if we use the dataReader, we get the right error message (it s a bonus.) So here is the part of the code I changed (for thoose who want to know) :

```
 public List<string> GetConfigurationValues(string configurationKey, int? idBusinessUnit, int? idDomain)
    {
        string conn = ConnectionStringHelper.GetIdentityConnectionString();
        string valueRes;

        int idConfigurationKey = 0;

        if (configurationKey == "PORTAL_THEME") { idConfigurationKey = 3; }
        else if (configurationKey == "LOGO_THEME") { idConfigurationKey = 4; }

        List<string> conf = new List<string>();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(conn))
        {
            dbConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = dbConnection.CreateCommand();
            SqlTransaction transaction;
            transaction = dbConnection.BeginTransaction("SampleTransaction");

            command.Connection = dbConnection;
            command.Transaction = transaction;

            try
            {

                command.CommandText = @"
                    SELECT Value 
                    FROM ConfigurationValue cv
                    INNER JOIN ConfigurationFilter cf ON cv.idConfigurationValue = cf.idConfigurationValue
                    INNER JOIN ConfigurationKey ck ON ck.idConfigurationKey = cf.idConfigurationKey
                    WHERE cf.idConfigurationKey = @ConfigurationKey
                    AND((cf.idDomain = @idDomain) OR(cf.idDomain IS NULL))
                    AND((cf.idBusinessUnit = @idBusinessUnit) OR(cf.idBusinessUnit IS NULL))";
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ConfigurationKey", idConfigurationKey));

            if (idBusinessUnit == null)
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@idBusinessUnit", DBNull.Value)); //DBNull.Value
            else
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@idBusinessUnit", idBusinessUnit));

            if (idDomain == null)
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@idDomain", null));// DBNull.Value
            else
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@idDomain", idDomain));


                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string theme = reader["Value"].ToString();
                        conf.Add(theme);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
                }
                reader.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Commit Exception Type: {0}", ex.GetType());
                Console.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", ex.Message);

            }

        }
        return conf;
    }
```